# How to open file with default application in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I have for example `.pdf` file (path to that file). How to open this file in default application (probably Acrobat Reader) from SWT application (for example on Button click) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
Program.launch(file);
```

to open the file (using the default application or creator).  From the javadoc:

> Launches the operating system executable associated with the file or URL (http:// or https://).  If the file is an executable then the executable is launched.  Note that a `Display` must already exist to guarantee that this method returns an appropriate result.

Note that there are some peculiarities in `Program.launch()` (or at least there were, though these may have been fixed in more recent versions of the runtime.)  I don't really remember the specifics of the bugs, but we do some checks to work around some issues:

1. If you're on a Unix platform, and you're specifying an absolute path, there may be trouble opening that file.  We prefix absolute paths with `/.` - so that `/tmp/foo` would be translated to `/./tmp/foo` - although I don't really remember the specifics of this bug any more than that.
2. On Windows, if you're trying to open a UNC path - for example `\\server\bar` - you need to wrap the string in double-quotes.  For example: `Program.open("\"\\server\bar\"");`

Comment: In my app on winXp and win7 a `Program.launch("C:\\dev\\test.pdf");` call work good - Acrobat Reader is opened and that's it. Thank You.

Comment: @edward-thomson in which package is "Program" class found??

Answer (score 1):

Try Desktop.open:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

Comment: Personally, I would prefer an SWT solution over an AWT one.  The SWT <-> AWT bridge is usually unnecessary and it's better not to use it unless you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help to find a decision: we ran into PermGen space trouble upon call `Desktop.open()` - which is in AWTpackage - out of our SWT application.

So I would prefer `Program.launch()` over `Desktop.open()` in a SWT-environment.